# How do you check for xsi:nil when parsing XML in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I haven't done too much XML parsing in the past, I have a page now that works fine in IE but fails in Firefox.  The XML document uses xsi:nil="true" for any values that are empty, it looks like the line below

```
<PlannedDistanceInMeters xsi:nil="true" />
```

I am grabbing needed text using the code below, which works on any nodes that do have text values (workout[i] is a set of nodes I am working through).  Also it's external XML so I can't change anthing on the XML side.

```
workouts[i].getElementsByTagName("PlannedDistanceInMeters")[0].firstChild.data;
```

For some reason IE completely seems to ignore this when attempting to grab text from "PlannedDistanceInMeters" and parses the document.  FF has an error in the console that shows up the moment my code attempts to parse that line and then the code fails.

Error: workouts[i].getElementsByTagName("PlannedDistanceInMeters")[0].firstChild is null

So what is the best way to check for these empty elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message itself is the solution. If the element has no children, `firstChild` will be `null`:

```
var e = workouts[i].getElementsByTagName("PlannedDistanceInMeters")[0].firstChild;
if (e == null) {
  // no child
} else {
  // access properties of e
}
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly check if an `xsi:nil` attribute is present:

```
var e = workouts[i].getElementsByTagName("PlannedDistanceInMeters")[0];
if (e.hasAttribute('xsi:nil')) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I quickly tried both solutions and the first one threw an error when run in IE, the second a different error. I thought I read somewhere that IE doesn't work the same as FF with hasAttribute.  But I did try a third option of hasChildNodes and that did work.  I just need to get to a machine with FF to test it now.  if it does work I'll mark this as answered, appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry to correct myself using .firstChild == null worked, not sure why it didn't work the first time I tried. thanks again!